# Nodejs with Express... post data not received in users.js from jade form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Windows 8.1 
Nodejs with Express 
Console output is...

```
$ npm start

> nodeauth@1.0.0 start e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth
> node ./bin/www

GET /users/register 200 525.115 ms - 2078
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 7.118 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 7.198 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.js 304 8.063 ms - -
Name is...  undefined
reqName...  undefined
PW is...  undefined
PW2 is..  undefined
POST /users/register 200 79.328 ms - 2340
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 7.847 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 7.378 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.js 304 8.676 ms - -
```

register.jade is...
The form loads OK and appears to be correct

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Register
    p Complete form for site registration
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            input.form-control(name='name', type='text', placeholder='Full Name')
        .form-group
            input.form-control(name='email', type='email', placeholder='Valid Email')
        .form-group
            input.form-control(name='username', type='text', placeholder='Username') 
        .form-group
            input.form-control(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Password')
        .form-group
            input.form-control(name='password2', type='password', placeholder='Confirm Password') 
        .form-group
            label Profile Image
            input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Register')
```

user.js is...
Values in the console.log statements are undefined in the console output.
The post method must not be sending anything from the form.
The values from the users.js errors array are displayed after submission.
Possible syntax error, but I'm not seeing it.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('register', {
        'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {
        'title': 'LogIn'
  });
});


router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    // Get form values
    var name        = req.body.name;
    var email       = req.body.email;
    var username    = req.body.username;
    var password    = req.body.password;
    var password2   = req.body.password2;

console.log('Name is... ', name);
console.log('reqName... ', req.body.name);
console.log('PW is... ', password);
console.log('PW2 is.. ', password2);

    // Check for image field
    if (req.body.profileimage) {
        console.log('Uploading file...');
        // File info
        var profileImageOriginalName    = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName            = req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImageMime            = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
        var profileImagePath            = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt                 = req.files.profileimage.extension;
        var profileImageSize            = req.files.profileimage.size;
    } else {
        var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';       // default image
    }

    // Form validation using Express validator
    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Valid Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    // Check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('register', {    // Pass values back in so user does not have to retype
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        // Create user object
        var newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                profileimage: profileImageName
            });

        // Create user
        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        // Success
        req.flash('success', 'You are registered and may now login');
        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Also files does not seem to be valid in the following context...

```
if (req.files.profileimage) console.log('Uploading file...');
```

Changed to...

```
if (req.body.profileimage) console.log('Uploading file...');
```

but have not been able to test yet.

as for Middleware...
The Package.json is...

```
{
  "name": "nodeauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "express-session": "*",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "multer": "^1.0.3",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

And the app.js file is...

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Handle file uploads
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
// ??? app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Handle Express sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Passport ... Note: Passport middleware must be after Express session middleware above
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
// In this example, the formParam value is going to get morphed into form body format useful for printing.
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Flash and Express-Messages
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

npm install with Multer did not like...

```
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}));
```

So I changed it to...

```
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
```

Not really sure what proplems that will cause yet

Comment: What middleware is the application using for parsing `multipart/form-data` body content? Support for this isn't built into ExpressJS.

Comment: Added package.json and app.js to the files listed. I believe I have all that should be needed at this point for the form to be able to post data to users.js

Comment: Changing <br>form(method='post',action='users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')<br>

Comment: Changing form(method='post',action='users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data') to form(method='post',action='users/register')  In register.jade enables posting form data to users.js but the values are not passed back to the form to pre-populate the fields from the check for errors code in users.js  Any thoughts why multipart/form-data does not work? I think I'll need it for image processing later.

Answer (score 1):

I face exactly the same problem like this before. As a way around the problem, I add **connect-multiparty** module to my project using npm command :

```
npm install connect-multiparty --save
```

then I add the code bellow on top of my route file (user.js) just after the express variable definition.

```
var express = require('express');
..

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
```

and finally I use **multipartMiddleware** in my router that accept files upload.

```
...
router.post('/register', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res, next){
...
...
}
```

Be aware that this module is not recommend to use in all routes, use it only to the ones in which you want to accept uploads. Check the documentation for more detail https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty

Answer (score 0):

for use multer you need insert it like middleware:

```
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
var fileLoad = upload.single('profileImage');
    router.route('/register')
     .post(fileLoad, function (req, res) { 
    .......
    }
```